# Where are the more powerful characters during the Tournament of Power?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball, dragon-ball-movies

In the Tournament of Power, why does Goku's team have Roshi, Krillin, Tien, etc. in it, even though most characters are much more powerful?

Where are Broly, Goten, Trunks, Majin Buu?

Comment: Broly wasn't canon as the answer said. And they didn't want to kids' life in danger, and Majin Buu fell asleep before the tournament, Cell, Nappa, and the rest of the Saiyans were dead. Though, it was the requirement of the script, as the Dragon Ball is so broken and lacks common sense due to the existence of senseless and imbalanced elements like Dragon Balls and Senzu Beans, that these could simply be revived, or woken up using those balls. And the bottom line was Universe 7 would've been the winner anyways, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT/UPDATE: Broly wasn't canon at the moment, and hence it didn't exist in the Dragon Ball anime series. He only existed in the movies, videogames, Dragon Ball Heroes etc.

Goten and Trunks were considered to be too inexperienced and young for the tournament of power and hence, were disregarded in favor of more experienced fighters such as Roshi, Tien, Krilin, etc. Currently, Goten and Trunks are looking after the island where Android 17 works as a park ranger.

Majin Buu was chosen to be part of the team, however, he fell asleep right before the tournament and didn't wake up and Goku decided to recruit Freiza to join their team for the tournament of power.

Comment: You mean that they changed him up for Freeza? & Aren't there, stronger fighters than Roshi, Tien, Krilin? I feel like even Cell would've accepted this invitation, to save himself, and besides..  considering that only an atom needs to survive, and then he can 'rebuild' I'm assuming that somewhere, Cell would still be alive

Comment: When Buu felt sleep, Goku went to look for Freezer in hell to have him as part of the team as replacement of Buu. I dont know why they didnt look for Cell, they didnt give any reason. May be Goku trusts more Freezer than Cell. Well, at this point Golden Freezer is stronger than Cell, but as replacement of the others. May be because they were already invited, or may be he thought it wasnt a good idea to have so many villains together in the team.

Comment: You're probably aware, but due to a movie release, Broly is canon to Super, so the first part of your answer is no longer accurate.

Comment: @ShayminGratitude updated the answer